# Is an artinian semisimple module-finite algebra over a noetherian complete local ring "symmetric"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R, m)$ be a noetherian complete local ring, and let $\Lambda$ be an artinian semisimple module-finite algebra over $R$. Let $D = \text{Hom}_R(-, E(R/m))$ denote the Matlis dual. My question is: whether $D\Lambda$ is isomorphic to $\Lambda$ as $\Lambda{-}\Lambda$-bimodules.

For motivation, in [[GN, Corollary 2.6.3](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251067011_Towards_a_theory_of_Bass_numbers_with_application_to_Gorenstein_algebras)], the authors have already shown that as $\Lambda$-modules one has $D\Lambda \cong \Lambda$. Meanwhile, it's well known that if in particular $R=k$ is a field, then any artinian semisimple algebra $\Lambda$ over $k$ satisfies $D\Lambda\cong\Lambda$ as bimodules (see e.g. [[L, Example 16.59](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0525-8)). Thus it's fair to guess the isomorphism $D\Lambda\cong \Lambda$ as bimodules also hold in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

The centre of a simple algebra $A$ is a field. For, if $a\in A$ is nonzero and central, then $Aa$ is a non-zero two-sided ideal, hence equals $A$. Thus $a$ is invertible, and given $b\in A$, multiplying $a^{-1}b-ba^{-1}$ by $a$ shows that $a^{-1}$ is central.

Thus if $\Lambda$ is simple and module-finite over some commutative $R$, then it is module-finite over its centre, so a CSA, and hence symmetric.

In general, a semisimple artinian algebra is a product of simple artinian algebras, so again if it is module-finite over some commutative $R$, then it is a finite product of CSAs and hence symmetric.

Comment: Apologize for ambiguity in the title. Here by "symmetric" I mean symmetric w.r.t. Matlis dual, instead of $k$-dual.